# Can you see all posts of a user posted in a particular group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I can go to the group and scroll down and down to visually look for the user's post (but may require scrolling for 10 minutes).

If I instead click on the user's profile, I don't see any of those posts. Those posts are all public in the group, and if I ask a user who is not a member of that group to see that post, he can see it as well.

Is there a way to find all posts of that user posted in that group? (searching for `ABCD group tom` only returns limited results.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

> [How do I search for posts in a group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/124679047612553?helpref=uf_permalink):
>
> To search for posts in a group:
>
> 1. Go to a group and click **Search this group** in the top right
> 2. Enter names or keywords that appear in the post or the comments of the post you're searching for

Comment: This isn't perfect, but searching for the person's name via this method usually yields good results

Comment: @Igy : I know :)